# tensorflow 1.4 needed on Jupyter Notebook (Python)

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I need an installation of old Tensorflow 1.4.x on my Jupyter Notebook, but I was not able to find an old source.

So I tried to install the latest version and then to migrate my Python scripts using the converter of the Tensorflow homepage. It did not work.

Also changing the behaviour of the TF 2.x to act as 1.x in the import statement of the .py scripts did not work - as often suggested here on stackoverflow.

So I really need an installation of TF 1.4.x

Any clue how to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select a specific version of [tensorflow from those available here](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/#history). Then you can download the required specific [`.whl` file](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/1.14.0/#files) and install that.

```
python -m pip install tensorflow-1.14.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

---

Optionally, you should be able to install with:

```
python -m pip install tensorflow==1.14.0
```

or

```
python -m pip install tensorflow==1.15.5
```

As long as there's a version available for Python version you're on. Ex. The 1.14.0 version is not available for Python 2.7, but it is available for 3.7.